# Definition of friend inside class

Tags: c++

Can i put definition of friend function / class inside another class? I mean something like this:

```
class Foo
{
    friend void foo() {} // 1
    friend class Bar {}; // 2
};
```

gcc compiles friend function, but can't compile friend class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can *define* a `friend` function in the friend declaration, and it has interesting behavior that cannot be obtained any other way (in the case of the enclosing type being a template).

You cannot *define* a `friend` class in the friend declaration, and there is no need for that. If you want to create a new type *inline* with full access, you can just create a *nested* type. Being a member it will have full access to the enclosing type. The only difference is that the type will not be found at namespace level, but you can add a typedef if needed (or alternatively, define the class at namespace level and just declare the friendship inside the class).

```
class Outer {
   int x;
   class Inner {
      static void f( Outer& o ) { o.x = 5; } // fine
   };
};
```

Comment: Any chance you could elaborate (or point to a link that does so) about "it has interesting behavior that cannot be obtained any other way (in the case of the enclosing type being a template)"

Comment: @DaveS: It will create a non-templated free function for each instantitating type, and it will do so in a way that is only visible through ADL --i.e. it won't pollute the enclosing namespace. So it *generically* creates non-templated functions with restricted visibility.

Answer (score 3):

n3337 11.3/2

> A class shall **not** be defined in a friend declaration. [ Example:
>
> ```
> class A {
> friend class B { }; // error: cannot define class in friend declaration
> };
> ```
>
> —end example ]

But you can use something like

```
class Foo
{
    friend void foo() {} // 1
    class Bar { };
    friend class Bar; // 2
};
```

Comment: A nested class already has access to the parents members so there is no need to make it a friend. `n3376 11.7 [class.access.nest]`

Answer (score 1):

You can make a nested class which, [according to defect report 45](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_defects.html#45), has access to the private members of the class. Is this what you meant?

"A nested class is a member and as such has the same access rights as any other member."

This may not work in all compilers because prior to this C++ standards defect report, nested classes were given no special access.

Comment: That defect report dates from 1998, I would expect most compilers to implement *at least* C++03, so this should work in *all* non-ancient compilers.

Comment: More relevantly, it also has access to the private members according to the C++11 standard.

Comment: Now part of the standard: `n3376 11.7 [class.access.nest]`

Comment: Most compilers surely implement at least C++03 as @DavidRodríguez-dribeas suggested, but I am occasionally reminded that an unfortunate few still use Visual Studio 6.0.

Answer (score 0):

Change the code to:-

```
class Foo 
{
     friend void foo() {} // 1
     friend class Bar ; // 2 
};
```